# Randomized smooth direction change

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a game where I want to do random movements. I wrote an algorithm that should calculate a direction and distance to move. Those destinations are points on a circumference of a circle. Imagine the character is always in the middle of this circle. In order to make direction changes smoother I thought each direction change should depend on the previous one.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace randomwalk
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int? previousAngle = null;
            while (true)
            {
                var angle = 0;
                Random rnd;
                if (previousAngle.HasValue)
                {
                    rnd = new Random();
                    var shift = 10;
                    angle = previousAngle.Value + rnd.Next(shift) - shift/2;
                    if (angle > 359)
                        angle -= 180;
                }
                else
                {
                    rnd = new Random();
                    angle = rnd.Next(359);
                }
                var radius = 160;
                var x = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Cos(angle) * radius);
                var y = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Sin(angle) * radius);
                Console.WriteLine("Moved to: X:{0}, Y:{1}", x, y);
                previousAngle = angle;
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is I don't get the results I expected. Each iteration here should make a shift in angles with a random number between 0-10. In actual results the angle changes far more than 10 degrees and even feels like it is totally random.

```
Actual results:
Moved to: X:5, Y:160
Moved to: X:18, Y:-159
Moved to: X:143, Y:-71
Moved to: X:109, Y:117
Moved to: X:109, Y:117
```

I also wonder how can I improve this and if there are already available motion algorithms which I can use, maybe better than this?

Comment: So... your description of the algorithm is your code block... but it doesn't produce the expected results.... so how exactly are we supposed to help you?

Comment: "The problem is I don't get the results I expected." So what are the results you expect instead?

Comment: @SamAxe sorry I couldn't think of a sample with right results. But the problem here is the angle change should be max 10 degrees on each iteration.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice sorry, I added an explanation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong, but you are currently using degrees when calling the [`Math.Cos`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.cos?view=netframework-4.8) and [`Math.Sin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.sin?view=netframework-4.8) framework functions.

Those functions expect the input parameter to be in [`radians`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian).

There is an easy conversion algorithm to convert from degrees into radians that has the form of (as seen in the linked topics on MSDN):

```
double angle = Math.PI * degrees / 180.0;
```

Having these should at least correct for this change, I didn't really validate the rest of the code or it's assumptions :)

You could see the changes in output in the following [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/F9bsA3), which gives an output similar to:

```
Moved to: X:73, Y:143
Moved to: X:82, Y:137
Moved to: X:92, Y:131
Moved to: X:101, Y:124
Moved to: X:109, Y:117
Moved to: X:117, Y:109
Moved to: X:124, Y:101
Moved to: X:131, Y:92
Moved to: X:137, Y:82
```